# NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory returns bogus path

Tags: ios, core-data, travis-ci

I've been trying to unit test an iOS project which uses Core Data. I'm using the usual Core Data stack which is generated by Xcode. The line failing is the following:

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()
```

On my mac it returns: `file:///Users/juliantejera/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{UNIQUE ID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{UNIQUE ID}/Documents/`

On travis: `file:///var/empty/Documents/`

Therefore my NSManagedObjectContext cannot be created and my app crashes. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week I was finally able to solve my problem by using a NSInMemoryStoreType for the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator whilst running unit tests.

```
var isRunningUnitTests = NSClassFromString("XCTest") != nil
var storeType = isRunningUnitTests ? NSInMemoryStoreType : NSSQLiteStoreType
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a combination of Kiwi and Realm:
I was initializing an object in the `context` block of the test spec, which in turn forced a Realm DB to be initialized. Not sure what exactly causes this weird action, but since then I take it as a rule of thumb to initialize variables in the `beforeAll` block.